# Opening csv files using vba

Tags: vba, opencsv

[CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzOSs_JJi7NWYmxaWm80d2lmR0k?usp=sharing)I am having a weird problem opening a CSV file. I have written a code to open a CSV file and process it in excel using vba. I could open only one specific CSV file but any other CSV files I am not able to open it or process it in excel I have no clue why. Why is that only one specific file is being read by the excel VBA. Below the code

```
Sub lithium()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
Dim PathInit As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Long, filecount As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim LR As Long
k = 2
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Opening the txt file
Dim myTxt
myTxt = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", MultiSelect:=False)



Open myTxt For Binary As #1
MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
Get #1, , MyData
Close #1
strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf) ' Saving the entire value of the text file into the array. every element in the array in the entire row of the txt file

 Dim strRow1() As String
 Dim strRow2() As String
 Dim strRow3() As String
 Dim strRow4() As String
 Dim strRow5() As String
 Dim strRow6() As String
 Dim nCount As Integer


 nCount = 1
 Dim nRowLenth As Integer
 nRowLenth = UBound(strData) - LBound(strData) ' Length of the total data array
 j = 3

For i = 18 To nRowLenth


          strRow1() = Split(strData(i), ";")

           Cells(j, 15).value = strRow1(0)
           Cells(j, 16).value = strRow1(1)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c0" Then Cells(j, 17).value = strRow1(2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c1" Then Cells(j, 18).value = strRow1(2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c4" Then Cells(j, 19).value = strRow1(2)
           Cells(j, 21).value = Left(Cells(j, 17).value, 2)
           Cells(j, 22).value = Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 2)
           Cells(j, 23).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 6), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 18).value, 4), 2)
           Cells(j, 23).NumberFormat = "0000"
           Cells(j, 24).value = Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 2)
           Cells(j, 26).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 12), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 10), 2)
           Cells(j, 27).value = Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 16), 2) & Right(Left(Cells(j, 19).value, 14), 2)
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c0" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c1" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _
           If Cells(j, 16).value = "c4" Then Cells(j, 1).value = Cells(j, 15).value Else _

           If Cells(j, 21).value = "" Then Cells(j, 2).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 2).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 21).value)
           If Cells(j, 22).value = "" Then Cells(j, 3).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 3).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 22).value)
           If Cells(j, 24).value = "" Then Cells(j, 4).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 4).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 24).value) - 40
        Cells(j, 5).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 25).value) - 40
           If Cells(j, 23).value = "" Then Cells(j, 5).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 5).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 23).value) - 32768
           If Cells(j, 26).value = "" Then Cells(j, 6).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 6).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 26).value)
           If Cells(j, 27).value = "" Then Cells(j, 7).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 7).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 27).value)
           If Cells(j, 27).value = "" Then Cells(j, 8).value = "#N/A" Else Cells(j, 8).value = Cells(j, 6).value - Cells(j, 7).value


    j = j +1
    Next

    End Sub
```

And also for that one specific file it works properly but I get one error index out of range which I do not know why. If someone could help

Comment: we have no idea either.  .... please post details of the structure of the csv file that works and the csv file that does not work.  .... are we supposed to guess which line gives you the error?  .... your question is similar to `i have this paintbrush, and it paints ok from one can of paint but does not paint well from the other can of paint. can you tell me why?`

Comment: sorry for the the CSV files are all of similar structure ... i will upload the files...

Comment: just paste a couple of lines from each into your question

Comment: @jsotola I have attached the CSV file...the one which works is called working and the other not working so i think this will help. (At the starting of the comments is the file)

Comment: you still have not said which line causes the error.   the format of the two files is not the same. single-step through your code and pay close attention to the value of `StrData(0)` after the `strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)` line, and you may discover the reason

Comment: The problem probably is due to having the delimiter set as strRow1() = Split(strData(i), ";") and having double ;; on the working file and none on the not working file how is it supposed to find the different bits if not separated by the delimiter.  This is the basis of your problem though I'm surprised the working file actually works..Also as an observation you haven't declared all your variables... what actually is the VBA trying to do? I guess you already know you can open CSV file directly in excel..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get a few ideas from one of these two solutions.

```
' Merge data from multiple sheets into seperate sheets
Sub R_AnalysisMerger2()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range
    Dim vFn, myFn As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsEmpty(SelectedFiles) Then Exit Sub

    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        vFn = Split(FileName, "\")
        myFn = vFn(UBound(vFn))
        myFn = Replace(myFn, ".csv", "")
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        vDB = WSA.UsedRange
        bookList.Close (0)
        Set Ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        ActiveSheet.Name = myFn
        Ws.Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

' Merge data from multime files into one sheet.
Sub R_AnalysisMerger()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Ws.UsedRange.Clear
    'change folder path of excel files here
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)


    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        With WSA
            vDB = .UsedRange
            Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If rngT.Row = 2 Then Set rngT = Ws.Range("a1")
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

            bookList.Close (0)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Ws.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```